# INSERT ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING efficiency (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

In Postgres, is it inefficient to perform an “INSERT… ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING” if >99.9% of the time the record exists and nothing is done?

E.g. let’s say I have a Node process which fetches 100k records which map to rows, of which 99,980 already exist. I could:

- Insert them all, but do nothing on uniqueness constraint violation
- Insert where not exists query
- Select all, do de-duplication “client” side, then insert only the 20 new ones

The first approach is easiest but I wonder if it will be too inefficient for Postgres. I have read that it increments serial numbers in such a “do nothing” case, but would it be OK if I skipped using a serial and used my unique field as the primary (string) key instead?

Comment: Could  you perhaps show us your table structure and even some sample data?

Comment: The two key fields are "ecosystem" and "package", which are unique together. Then there would be an "id" column which would either be an auto-incrementing serial, or a concatenation of ${ecosystem}-${package}.

Comment: Thanks for that - but it's best practice to put any relevant information into the question and then use the comments to inform the person who requested it. That way, the question remains the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth). Also, there's a certain amount of cogntive dissonance in having to scroll down through the comments and then back up to the question itself. The actual table DDL would be great! :-)

Comment: So basically you have to compare 100k rows that are in the database against 100k rows that are client-side? So you have 100k rows that need to go through the network no matter what method you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` is as efficient as it can be, but the question is beside the point.

It may well be that an `UPDATE` is faster, but that `UPDATE` wouldn't do the right thing for 0.1% of the rows, so it is not a solution.

Note: it is always possible to be faster if you don't have to be correct.